# iptables, redirect from ip address to loopback

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I have an Apache web server listening in 127.0.0.1:63280
eth0 has IP: 172.200.200.200.1, and try to connect from workstation IP 172.200.200.200

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 172.200.200.200.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 63280 
         -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:63280
```

With `tcpdump -i` lo, I can't see any traffic to web server.

Is there any problem with NAT and loopback?

Comment: `172.200.200.200.1` is not a valid IP, maybe it's your problem... (or a typo in your question?)

Comment: sorry, it's a mistake, ip address is 172.200.200.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think found the answer !!

Linux kernel drops all packets to dest 127.0.0.1 that not from 127.0.0.1